# what could cause a js function that has been defined to be unable to be called

Tags: javascript

I have some JS code which adds elements to a page when a button has been clicked but for some reason when the button is pressed it tells me that the function I am trying to call returns error

> Uncaught TypeError: addstep is not a function
>
> buttons.onclick @ add.js:124

```
function addstep(x)
{
    if(x === undefined)
    {
        x = 1;
    }

    // Define Variables
    var steps = document.getElementById("steps");
    var addstep = document.getElementById('addstep');
    var newstep = document.createElement("textarea");
    newstep.name = "step" + x;
    newstep.idName   = "txtr";
    newstep.className = "txtr";

    var step = "Step " + x + ":&nbsp;";

    steps.innerHTML = step;
    steps.appendChild(newstep);

    x++;

    var buttons = document.createElement("button");
    var text    = document.createTextNode("Add Step");
    buttons.appendChild(text);
    buttons.onclick = function(){ addstep(x);};
    addstep.appendChild(buttons);    
}
```

I can't seem to find the problem in my code I load this code on runtime which works but not when the button is pressed??

Comment: `var addstep = document.getElementById('addstep');` make `addstep` another variable now.

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
var addstep = document.getElementById('addstep');
```

you define a new variable called `addstep`. This one shadows the external one, it's the only one you see from inside the function. And it's not a function, so it can't be called.

The simplest solution is to give to this variable another name.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, in js a function is also a variable, don't you change your variable somewhere else ?

In the example below, you ca see that *asd* is no more a function but a number. Try renaming.

```html
<script>
  function addstep(x)
  {
  }
  
  addstep = 1;
  alert("typeof asd = " + typeof(asd));
</script>
```